# ObjC Unit test allowsExternalPlayback

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I have an AVPlayer where I want to check if allowsExternalPlayBack is set to false. So in my code I have something like

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.apple.com"];
AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
player.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;
```

When I try to test this in a unit test, even in following code, This does not work.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.apple.com"];
AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
player.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;
XCTAssertFalse(player.allowsExternalPlayback);
```

Result: allowsExternalPlayback is still YES
Expected result: allowsExternalPlayback is NO (at the point of assertion)